# How can I do a global select over multiple tables in the database or something equivalent?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a series of tables in the same database. The table names are separated in groups i.e. the tables in the same groups have the same prefix.
These tables share a column (at least one) with the same information and the same column name (except only a couple of tables that have the column name different).
What I am interested in, is knowing which tables have specific values. I.e. I would like to get the table names that their column have a specific value OR equivalently I would like to do a `SELECT * WHERE COLUMN=value` over all tables and get all the records. I would prefer to have the table names unless it is too difficult.
What I did to get a result was the following:
I wrote manually a select in an editor over **all** tables of one group (i.e that have the same prefix) and the where clause.
I copy/pasted all these selects and run them in the query cli.
Then I did a replace all in the editor and replaced the table names to the second group and copy/pasted again and run this.
I kept on doing replace/copy/paste for all tables (and also did replace for the column name when needed).
This seems to do what I want but it feels stupid to me.
I think there must be a more "professional" way than this method but I don't know how.
What would be the best way for this?
In my way if I had another e.g. 5 groups I would have to do this over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may make may be able to make things a little easier by creating views over the tables that you are interested in : 
something like

```
CREATE VIEW group_one_view AS 
SELECT 'taba' as tab_name, field1 FROM table_a
UNION ALL
SELECT 'tabb' as tab_name, field1 FROM table_b
UNION ALL
SELECT 'tabc' as tab_name, diff_field_name FROM table_c
```

then you can use group_one_view like it is a table

```
select * from group_one_view where field1 = 'cheese'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a09b4/1

**EDIT**

you may be able to get a little help from the information_schema (would need to finish up the query somewhat - but could save a little keyboard work)

```
SELECT CONCAT(  'select ''', table_name,  ''' tab_name, field1 from ', table_name,  ' union all ' ) 
FROM information_schema.`TABLES` 
WHERE table_name LIKE  'group_prefix_%'
```

Comment: +1 because it is a nice option.But it is equally tedious to write as with my dumb method.Isn't it?